# js debounce logic understanding

Tags: javascript

Wanted to see if experts here help explain how to understand the below debounce logic better. I got this from an Udemy course but the video only got so much explanation. From the code below.. this is what I understand it does - everytime an "input" is detected setTimeout inside debounce function will execute and after 1 second it'll remove the timeout.

How does the spread operator and the "args" come into play in this?

I understand the spread operator takes in an array and then "spreads" it out as separate arguments into the function parameter. Am I misunderstanding how the func.apply works here? How does the return(...args) read the input value arguments?

It seems like "onInput" is func and the return values from "onInput" is passed as arguments to ...args?

```
const debounce = func => {
  let timeoutID;
  return (...args) => {
    if(timeoutID) clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(
      () => func.apply(null, args),
      1000
    );
  };
}

const onInput = event => {
  fetchData(event.target.value);
};

input.addEventListener("input", debounce(onInput));
```

Comment: _"and after 1 second it'll remove the timeout."_ - Or if there's another "input" before the last "input" executes `onInput`

Comment: In this case `...` is not the spread operator. It's the ["rest parameter" syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters): _"The rest parameter syntax allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array"_

Comment: _"...as an array"_ - And that's exactly what [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) expects (if needed) as its second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to clarify:

- `debounce` returns a (anonymous arrow) function. It doesn't do much more than that, except that it provides a closure for the variables `func` (the argument passed to `debounce`) and `timeoutID`. So when you call `debounce(onInput)` the returned function will know about `onInput`.
- The above-mentioned returned function becomes the handler for the `input` event. So when that event triggers that anonymous arrow function is called with the event object as argument. So `args` will be `[event object]`. This anonymous function will clear any pending timer event and will schedule a new one that will call `func.apply(null, args)`.
- When the timer expires without being cleared, then `func.apply(null, args)` will be called. We know what `func` is: `onInput` and we know what `args` is: `[event object]`. So that means we effectively call `onInput` with the event object as argument.

As to your questions:

> How does the spread operator come into play in this?

It is the rest syntax, and allows to capture all the arguments into one array.

> How does the "args" come into play in this?

As explained above, as the event handler is called with one argument, `args` will be initialised to an array with the same arguments that the event handler would get, i.e. with the event object.

> Am I misunderstanding how the `func.apply` works here?

All you wrote about it is that the function will execute. `apply` is a method that calls the function with a specific value for `this` (which is not the goal here, so just `null` is provided), and with an array that should be used as arguments in the call. As `args` is exactly that array of arguments we got, and we just want to pass them on, that is what is passed here as well.

It should be said that in modern JavaScript you'd achieve the same result with `func(...args);`

> How does the `return(...args)` read the input value arguments?

First of all that is not the complete statement. The complete statement includes the whole arrow function, which is the object that is returned here. Like explained above, `debounce` returns a function (object).

This code "only" returns that function, it does not read input value arguments. It provides the function that will later do this. Realise that `debounce` is called **now**, while that returned function is only called **when the event fires**.

### Rewritten...

It may clarify things when rewriting the code in a slightly different way. I hope it better highlights the difference between *returning* a function and *executing* it. This can happen at different times.

```
function debounce(func) {
    let timeoutID;

    // Define a local function. Don't execute yet.
    // It takes any arguments, as it will just remember them
    // for passing them to the original function later on (after timer).
    function debouncedFunc(...args) {
        // If we had a pending timer job, clear it, as we want a new one.
        if (timeoutID !== undefined) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        }
        // Create a function to execute later. It should itself
        //   execute func with the arguments we already know about.
        function executeFunc() {
            // This is the more modern syntax to do func.apply(null, args):
            // It is easier to read; we just call func with some known arguments
            func(...args);
        }
        // Schedule that function to run later, and get a handle for that job
        timeoutID = setTimeout(executeFunc, 1000);
    }

    // Return the new function object to the caller.
    // They can call it with some arguments, or let 
    // some other API call it for them (like with addEventListener)
    return debouncedFunc;
}

function onInput(event) {
    fetchData(event.target.value);
}

// Get a function object
const debouncedInputHandler = debounce(onInput); 

// Make that function the event handler
input.addEventListener("input", debouncedInputHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you trincot! I have been trying to break this down but couldn't on my own...=[ so another question regarding return (...args).. Why does this part matter in the code? so let me know if i am envisioning this correctly.. every user input in the input field is captures from "func" and then passed into return (...args) as separate arguments right?

Comment: It is bit troubling that you speak of `return (...args)` like that. There is `return` and there is `(...args) => { ......... }`. The second is a *function*, including a parameter part and a body. The parameter part and the body belong to the function object, and the `return` returns that function object. It doesn't return the parameter declaration `(...args)`. That parameter declaration is a required element in a function definition. With that in mind, please can you reread my answer?

Comment: Thank you trincot ! I've been interpreting the return (..args) as  it is returning arguments.. but it should be viewed as an anonymous arrow function (function without a name!!). Still absorbing your comments...but thank you so much for the guidance so far.